# Assume $f(x): x\in R$ differentiable, $s(x)$ only takes two values $1$, $-1$ on $R$. If $g(x)=s(x)f(x)$ is differentiable, can one show $s$ constant?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Assume that $f(x): x\in \mathbb{R}$ differentiable, $s(x)$ only takes two values $1$ and $-1$  on $\mathbb{R}$. If $g(x)=s(x)f(x)$ is differentiable, can one show that $s(x)$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}$?

(It seems to me that it brings some convenience to prove the continuity of $s(x)$ instead, and the continuity of $s(x)$ on points $x$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ follows easily from the fact that $s(x) = \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$.)

If the argument is false, **can the given assumptions be strengthened to make it right?** (**Somehow I think it might be helpful to assume $f''(x) \neq 0$** for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, but I cannot see the solid connection between the assumption and the conclusion.)

My question arised from the following exercise: If $|p(x)| = \frac{|\ln x|}{x^2}$, and $p$ is differentiable, show that $p(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x^2}$ or $p(x) = -\frac{\ln x}{x^2}$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: When your question gets answers, it is inappropriate to change the question into another question to which those answers do not apply.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your advice. I will adapt my question and reopen one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take$$
f(x)=x^2\quad\text{and}\quad s(x)=\begin{cases}
                                    1&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\
                                    -1&\text{ otherwise.}
                                  \end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. However, $s$ is not constant.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also wonder if the argument is true when we add to the original conditions that $f′(x)≠0$  for every $x$ satisfying $f(x)=0$, can you please help?

Comment: If you always have $f'(x)\ne0$ then, yes, $s$ has to be constant.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I have opened a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504441/assume-fx-is-such-that-fx0-sx-only-takes-two-values-1-1-on) which includes the hypothesis $f'(x)\neq 0$ for every zero of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous.  Suppose that $s(x)$ is not constant.  Then, there is a finite interval $(x_0-h/2,x_0+h/2),h>0$ in which exist points $x_{1,0},x_{1,1}$ where $s(x_{1,0}) = -1,s(x_{1,1}) = 1$.  Then,
$$|f(x_{1,0})s(x_{1,0})-f(x_{1,1})s(x_{1,1})| = |f(x_{1,0})+f(x_{1,1})| \approx 2|f(x_{1,0})|.$$

If $f(x_{1,0}) \ne 0$, we see that
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{|(fs)(x_{0,1})-(fs)(x_{1,0})|}{|x_{0,1}-x_{1,1}|} = 2\frac{|f(x_{1,0})|}{h}.$$

Because $h$ can be as small as we wish, the above limit cannot exist at $x_{0,1}$.

So, for $fs$ to be differentiable with $s$ not constant, we need to require $f(x_{0,1}) = 0$, which @AnotherUser has done in their example.

Comment: "there is a point $x_0$ where WLOG $s$ changes from $-1$ to $+1$": this seems to assume that $s$ must have only jump discontinuities, which isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: @GregMartin, but the OP states that $s$ can only have values of $\pm 1$.  Also, question implies that $s$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.  What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps $s(x)=1$ when $x$ is rational and $s(x)=-1$ when $x$ is irrational.

Comment: @GregMartin, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Doug Thank you. I think one can also show that $g(x) = f(x)s(x)$ is differentiable with $s(x)$ not continuous on some point $x$ only if $x$ is a zero of $f$, by the fact that $s(x) = \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$.

Comment: @Doug I also wonder if we require $f'(x) \neq 0$ for every zero of $f(x)$, will the constancy of $s(x)$ follow? I have opened a [new quetion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504441/assume-fx-is-such-that-fx0-sx-only-takes-two-values-1-1-on) for this.